# math stack exchange coding link - new user

Tags: discussion

Anyone can point me where I can find out how to code certain things when posting on this site, like making exponents and such - I have several questions I need to ask but have reserved them until I get a better idea on presentation.

ANy help would be much appreciated

Comment: oh okay I'll check the gen. tutorial, thanks, sorry about that